# Java Parsing Wiki Syntax with regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm making an application to generate HTML document from [wiki markup](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki_markup). And I figured regex was the right way to replace markup to HTML tags. I came up with a working regex to find markup, but I couldn't find Java API to replace it while retaining the sentence.

**The regex suggested by an answer:**
`--([^-]+)--` (regex `--([^-])+--` doesn't behave well with Java API. Moving `+` inside the capturing group solves the problem.)

**Example:**
`--This is strike--` should be `<strike>This is strike</strike>`
But cases like `This is ---- normal text` or `---Triple hyphens---` should NOT be replaced.
However, cases like `--striked----also striked--` works.

Only Java 6 please.
Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Based on an answer, it seems I can use `$1` for this purpose.

Comment: What you're looking for is [Capturing Groups](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html). Sounds like you need to learn a lot more about regex, because capturing groups are pretty basic regex.

Comment: [Don't reinvent the wheel](https://blog.makk.es/java-libs-for-processing-wiki-markup.html) unless you're doing this as a exercise.

Comment: I think your regex won't work either. For example, it won't match `--This is strike with-hyphen-inside the text--`

Comment: @tkausl I'm actually trying to parse a variant.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks, it seems capturing groups was the thing I was looking for. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking one of my friend, I got an answer.

`--([^-]+(-[^-]+)*)--` Will work correctly and capture subject string as `$1`

Answer (score 2):

Groups `(...)` are numbered from 1 in order of occurrence.
Postfix operator `*` = 0 or more, `+` is 1 or more.

```
s = s.replaceAll("--([^-]+)--", "<strike>$1</strike>");
```

Comment: I confirmed regex `--([^-])+--` doesn't behave well with Java 6 API. Moving `+` inside the capturing group solved the problem.